# XML Parser : How to avoid null pointer exception

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

when given *key is not exist* it throws `NPE`.

```
String nodeValue = eElement.getElementsByTagName(key).item(0).getTextContent();
    if (nodeValue == null || nodeValue.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return nodeValue;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this

 String nodeValue=null;     
if(eElement!=null && eElement.getElementsByTagName(key)!=null     
 && eElement.getElementsByTagName(key).item(0)!=null ){
 nodeValue = eElement.getElementsByTagName(key).item(0).getTextContent();
}
return nodeValue;
```

Comment: Calling getElementsByTagName() three times seems extravagent.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of the element of your expression is null

```
String nodeValue = null;
if (eElement != null && eElement.getElementsByTagName(key) != null && eElement.getElementsByTagName(key).length > 0) {
    nodeValue = eElement.getElementsByTagName(key).item(0).getTextContent();
}
```

Comment: there is still a chance eElement.getElementsByTagName(key).item(0)  can be null and .getContent() may end up in NPE.

Comment: No, if getElementsByTagName(key).length is > 0 then the elements at position 0 exists. It is not a manual array constructed by hand that can have null values in some position. This is a structure related to the dom